# Failed to lookup view in node express for jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, pug

I'm using Jade template engine to replace to replace my variables:; I have tried the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
        var html= res.render(jade.renderFile('test', {"message": "test1", "title": "test2"}));
        res.render(html);
});
module.exports = router;
```

and the following is my test.jade:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

But I keep the folowing error:

message:

```
> "Failed to lookup view
> "<html><head><title>test2</title></head><body><h1>test1</h1></body></html>"
> in views directory "C:\node\myProj\views"",
```

Alos here is my setup for jade in my app.js:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
```

So what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated...

**UPDATED to use res.render:**

Updated to use app.render:

So I changed my route to:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app;
module.exports = function (_app) {
    app = _app;
    return router;
}
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    app.render('test', {"message": "test1", "title": "test2"}, function(err, html){
         res.render(html);
    });  
});
```

and now I'm caling in this way in app.js:

```
var test = require('./routes/test');
app.use(test(app));
```

Now it gives me:

```
> "Failed to lookup view
> "<html><head><title>test2</title></head><body><h1>test1</h1></body></html>"
> in views directory "C:\node\myProj\views""
```

Although res.render works fine:

```
res.render('test', {"message": "test1", "title": "test2"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are close but your request handler needs slight adjustment:

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('test', {"message": "test1", "title": "test2"}));
});
```

- Because you set the view engine, `res.render` is now smart enough to do your jade for you
- You can also omit the `./views` prefix and `.jade` suffix again because express now understands these as defaults
- You also don't need to require `jade` in your router file anymore

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation!

Comment: One more quetion; how if I want to have the the rendered string with replaced variables?

Comment: In others words I dont want to use the replaced rendered template as response object data; in fact, I want to get replaced and rendered html string and send it as an email....So I want the result as  a tring

Comment: Use `app.render` for that.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me, but app.render is not working although res.render was working; I updated my question with the progress; could you please help me; I guess we are almost there...

Comment: Once you have `app.render` that gets your from jade to html. Then if you already have html you send it with `res.send(html)`. `res.render` is only for when you don't have HTML yet.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother again; but does app.render work with emailContent which is read from AWS.S3 as well, if not, is there any solution for rendeing with the contenct which is read from S3 as well? sorry man....

Comment: Please post a separate question for that.